# HttpInterceptor refactor error message

Tags: angular, http, angular-http-interceptors

I have an HttpInterceptor and I'd like it to refactor my error to remove brackets.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public auth: AuthProvider, public app: App, private global: GlobalVariablesProvider) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {

      }
    }, (err: any) => {
      // modify err here?
    });
  }
}
```

I can't seem to modify `err` directly and I'm not sure how to pass the error along after modifying it.  The modification I'd like to make to `err` is:

```
err.error.replace(/\[|]/, '')
```

Comment: This might help https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18348, note `.flatMap()` and `Observable.create()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In interceptors and HTTP error will be caught with handle(request).catch(...)

What you can do is :

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(public auth: AuthProvider, public app: App, private global: GlobalVariablesProvider) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request)
            .do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                    // do what you want here if your have to
                }
            })
            .catch((err: any) => {
                if (err && err.error) {
                    err.error = err.error.replace(/\[|]/, '');
                }
                return Observable.throw(err);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use `.catch()` instead of the onError positional callback in order to `return`?

Comment: The interceptor method return an observable not an observer. And when you have a http error from server i think the only way to catch it is to use catch operator. But maibe im wrong

Comment: From my implementation of an error interceptor to redirect to login when we get a `403` I use the positional callback, like in OP's post. I was just curious if they are functionally equivalent since I just never tried `.catch()`.